Conversion from RadarScan to RadarTracks message type
I just tried to implement the Autoware Radar Sensing data pipeline and noticed that Autoware requires RadarTracks as input message type. My customer only gets RadarScan messages. Is there already a ROS 1 or ROS 2 node for converting RadarScan to RadarTracks? If not, do you know algorithms I could use to write a node myself?
Thanks a lot 

In general I think that you could write an algorithm to take in the raw ranges and upconvert with an estimator. However it's a very open ended problem with a lot of parameters to potentially tune. I believe that the more advanced radar sensors do this internally with extra data that's not exposed into the RadarScan message abstraction.
